# Setting up a node.js & express project

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to javascript and node.js, and I want to create a login and sign-up screen. I have my HTML and CSS already made. How would I set up my project to render my HTML and start my server? All I have is `const server = http.createServer`. I have looked at tutorials online but I am unable to figure it out.

Thank you to everyone who helps!

Comment: Hi, for this specifically take a look at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-deliver-html-files. I highly recommend you first learn about node js and express before doing this.

Comment: Thank you, I will look at that.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me. I was able to render my HTML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to set up a project and serve static files (HTML, CSS, JS..). In Nodejs, you can do it easily with [Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). For example, you can have this in your `server.js` :

```
// require libraries
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const ejs = require("ejs");

// initiate express app
const app = express();

// config express app
app.use('/', express.static("public"));// express app serves static files (css, js...) in "public" folder
// to include the stylesheet at public/css/style.css, we use  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
// to include the script at public/script/script.js, we use <script src="/script/script.js"></script>
// you can put index.html in /public folder

app.listen(5000, function () { console.log("Server is listening on port 5000") });

// your page will be available at http://localhost:5000
```

And the folder structure is

```
node_modules
public
  index.html
  css
    style.css
  script
    script.js
server.js
```

I've created a working project [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/express-ejs-sandbox0?path=app.js%3A1%3A0). The code is self-documented. Feel free to test it :). In the boilerplate, you don't need the ejs part, just put your index.html file in the `/public` folder.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot. How did you learn javascript and node? Do you have any articles or tutorials that I could look at?

Comment: You can look at https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/, https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp. Nodejs/ javascript has many resources online :) When you're families with the language, try to learn & apply some best practices from [here](https://github.com/goldbergyoni/nodebestpractices)